# Set up a sub-domain for multiple Public IPs

Tags: ip, bind

I hope you can help me.

I have 5 Public IP's in an subnet `186.121.200.X/29`

I have `example.com` addressed to one of those public IPs, and some subdomains that point to the rest of them.

Now, I have other 5 Public IP's in another subnet `190.181.15.Y/29`

**My question is:**

*Can I configure `example.com` to also point to an IP of the subnet `190.181.15.Y/29` ?*

*How can I do it?*

I have these configuration files:

```
(named.conf.options)
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
                // Google Public DNS (IPv4)
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
                // Google Public DNS (IPv6)
                2001:4860:4860::8888;
                2001:4860:4860::8844;
                // ADSL router
                186.121.200.X;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
(named.conf.local)
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.direct";
        allow-query { any; };
};
zone "206.121.186.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.reverse";
        allow-query { any; };
};
(db.direct)
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example.com. root.example.com. (
                             11         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@               IN       NS     example.com.
@               IN       MX     10    mail
@               IN       A      186.121.206.X1
www             IN       A      186.121.206.X1
mail            IN       A      186.121.206.X2
subdomain1      IN       A      186.121.206.X3
subdomain2      IN       A      186.121.206.X4
subdomain3      IN       A      186.121.206.X5

(db.reverse)
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     example.com. root.example.com. (
                              8         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      example.com.
X1     IN      PTR     ns.example.com.
X1     IN      PTR     www.example.com.
X2     IN      PTR     mail.example.com.
X3     IN      PTR     subdomain1.example.com.
X4     IN      PTR     subdomain2.example.com.
X5     IN      PTR     subdomain3.example.com.
```

EDIT:
I have tried doing the following:

```
(db.direct)
...
subdomain4      IN       A      190.181.15.Y1
```

```
(db.reverse)
...
Y1     IN      PTR     subdomain4.example.com.
```

When saving files and restarting bind, the subdomain responds to a ping.

`ping subdomain4.example.com`

`PING subdomain4.example.com (190.181.15.Y1) 56(84) bytes of data.`

But when accessing subdomain by browser, it redirects to Public IP. It is not kept with the name of the subdomain.

What is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question (and your obfuscation does not help, if you provided real names everything would have been simpler), but for "Can I configure mydomain.com to also point to the second subnet of Public IPs?" yes you can have multiple `A` and/or `AAAA` records for a single name. Just add them in your zone. (and stop using `mydomain` for obfuscation as it is obviously not your domain and yet it exists... please use `example.com` or the `.example` TLD if really needed...)

Comment: Is there a lot of trouble using mydomain.com instead of example.com? If I have led anyone to believe that mydomain.com is my property, sorry for that. Could you specify an answer with an example please? Or some url will help me.

Comment: "Is there a lot of trouble using mydomain.com instead of example.com? " Yes. Because people copy and paste and hence create traffic where not traffic should be. It is exactly for bad behaviors like that that some TLDs like .home or .mail will never exist: they were too much abused in documentation.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek. I already edited the question. Can you put an exemplified solution, please?

Comment: (From what I understand in your question, which is not clear, in part because of your obfuscation), you just need to put 5 `A` records, same name for all 5, different IP addresses. Which is already what I said in my first comment in fact. Which is also @DubStep answer, so at this stage it is not clear what more you need.

Comment: It does not work. Because when I register more A records directed towards the second subnet, it no longer returns me with the name of the subdomain. It only does a redirect, but the Public IP appears. The first is 186.121.200.X/29 and the second is 190.181.15.Y/29

Comment: Not to mention that mydomain.com is a pretty sketchy business that I would not be comfortable directing anyone to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton. The question is already edited. Could you provide an answer please?

Comment: The reason a redirect to the public IP happens is because that is what the web server is configured to do.  DNS only resolves things.  It does not perform redirects or any other HTTP functions, as that is HTTP's job.

I'm not sure what you are asking at this point?  Do you want to redirect something?  Have a web server listen at multiple addresses?  What is your expectation from an end user using a web browser perspective.  As in, person visits my site at address A.  In their browser they see address (A? B? C?) and on the page see <insert content they should see>.  Then repeat for B & C.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple entries for any A record.  You'd just add another entry with whatever additional IP(s) you want to the zone file.

Comment: Please, can you describe your answer with an example?

Comment: It's part of the DNS RFC for what an address record is.  I guess this is what you are looking for?
https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/a-record/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple ip addresses for a single record in a zone, but you can't control (without additional resources) which ip will be resolved for each request, there'll be random resolutions (e: for two ip addresses, 50% of possibilities for each one)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you are trying to do:

```
subdomain1      IN       A      186.121.206.X3
```

Then point the reverse IP of:

```
190.181.15.Y      IN       PTR      subdomain1.example.com.
```

Based on my experience, the organization who had received the direct IP allocation from ARIN, APNIC, AFRINIC, RIPE (regional IP registrant organization) is able to create a PTR record for the IP address that they received from their regional IP registrant.

I do not believe any regional IP registrant ever provided IPs that are smaller than a class C (/24).

So, you can do below (multiple A records for the same subdomain), but the result IP when looking up subdomain1.example.com is randomly selected

```
subdomain1      IN       A      186.121.206.X3
subdomain1      IN       A      190.181.15.Y3
```

Unless you own 190.181.15.Y, even though you create PTR record like below for the IPs, those PTR records more likely won't be available publicly unless on a rare situation that the owner of the IPs provided you an option to create PTR records for their IP address:

```
15.181.190.in-addr.arpa. IN SOA ns.example.com. 
Y3      IN       PTR      subdomain1.example.com.
```

Comment: I have edited the question, with the results of the application of your suggestion.

Comment: Maybe it is the web server that is redirecting. There can be so many variables causing your issue and this is not something I can troubleshoot especially because I'm not clear about what you're doing.

Comment: I will try again, and I will respond with the results obtained.